# Moses' age when before the burning bush

Tags: moses

I am trying to find Moses’ age when he was standing before the Burning Bush before delivering the Israelites from slavery. Later in Scripture it says he was 80 years when he first spoke to Pharaoh. Does scripture give any idea how old he was before the Burning Bush, or he was also around 80 years old at that time?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This is a good question for this site. If you have any other question, please make sure it fits one of the [question types that the community finds acceptable.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac) I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 10):

Scripture tells us Moses was 40 when the Egyptian struck the slave:
Acts 7:22-29

> 22 And Moses was learned in all the wisdom of the Egyptians, and was mighty in words and in deeds. 23 And when he was full forty years old, it came into his heart to visit his brethren the children of Israel.

And then...in Acts 7:30

> And when forty years were expired, there appeared to him in the wilderness of Mount Sinai an angel of the Lord in a flame of fire in a bush.

In Exodus 7:7, we see the age at which Moses (and Aaron) when they go to Pharaoh:

> Moses was 80 years old and Aaron 83 when they spoke to Pharaoh..."

So Moses was 40 when he killed the Egyptian, and 80 at both the time of the Burning Bush and the meeting with Pharaoh.

Comment: So your conclusion is that less than a year's time passed between the Burning Bush and Moses' first appearance before Pharaoh?

Comment: Exodus 7:7: "Moses was 80 years old and Aaron 83 when they spoke to Pharaoh..." So yes, that is my conclusion.

Comment: This doesn't really say much more than the OP already stated. -1

Comment: The OP asked if there was any indication of his age when he was before Burning Bush. I fail to see how answering with Scripture that he was 80 at that time. The question ends with "Does scripture give any idea how old he was before the Burning Bush, or he was also around 80 years old at that time?" - the answer is he was 80, per Scripture.

Comment: @Jesse That depends on whether "before" is indicating time or location. When Moses stood before the burning bush, he was 80.  Before the burning bush in terms of time would include 40, 41, 42, 43, 44...

Comment: Nothing is assumed here. Scripture clearly states Moses was 40 when he killed the Egyptian, 40 years later he saw the Bush (80; "forty years had expired"), and 80 at the time of they met Pharaoh. All right there.

Answer (score 1):

He was about 80

The timeline would look like this:

> 0 - [*Moses is born*]
>
> 40 - **Acts 7:23-24 ESV** When he was forty years old, it came into his heart to visit his brothers, the children of Israel. And seeing one of them being wronged, he defended the oppressed man and avenged him by striking down the Egyptian.
>
> 80 - **Acts 7:30 ESV** Now when forty years had passed, an angel appeared to him in the wilderness of Mount Sinai, **in a flame of fire in a bush**.
>
> 80 - **Exodus 7:3 ESV** Now Moses was eighty years old, and Aaron eighty-three years old, when they spoke to Pharaoh.
>
> >80 - **Number 32:13 ESV**  And the Lord's anger was kindled against Israel, and he made them wander in the wilderness **forty years**, until all the generation that had done evil in the sight of the Lord was gone.
>
> 120 - [*dead*]

Comment: This is false, Acts 7:30 says it was 40 year after killing the Egyptian that he saw the Burning Bush.

Comment: @Jesse You are correct! I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Moses 80 years old

Acts 7:23:  "When Moses was 40 years old, he decided to visit his fellow Israelites.  He saw one of them being mistreated by an Egyptian, so he went to his defense and avenged him by killing the Egyptian.  Acts 7:30: "After forty years had passed [after Moses killed the Egyptian], an angel appeared to Moses in the flames of a burning bush in the desert near Mount Sinai. See [Exodus 2:1-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%202%3A1-25&version=NIV).  Notice in verses 22-23 that after Moses got married to Zipporah, he had a son (Gershom), and the king of Egypt died.  Verse 23 says, "During that long period, the king of Egypt died.  The Israelites groaned in their slavery and cried out, and their cry for help because of their slavery went up to God."  He was 40 years old when he killed the Egyptian, and after a long period (marriage and the king died), he saw the burning bush.  It seems to me that it would be correct to date Moses at 80 years of age when God called him (spoke to him) from the burning bush.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. I've done some editing to bring it a little closer to site standards. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer) Meanwhile, I hope you'll stick around and browse some of the other questions and answers here.